# How to create a histogram of regression results stored as a list in R

Tags: r

[image: Link to image]

I am trying to create a histogram from several regression coefficients in R using the walk() function preferably that were split as a list. As a result, each regression on the main dataset (split by country) outputs as a list, so I'm having trouble extracting the coefficients and then to effectively plot them. A sample of the output is attached, and this would be what has been used thus far resulting to get this stacked list:

```
library(dplyr) 
library(purrr)

country <- split(df, df$country)

country_regression <- map(country, safely(fit_reg))
```

Is there anything that can be done so that I would be able to `walk(data, hist)` to create a histogram of the distribution of coefficient values? Thank you so much for your guidance

Comment: Please include calls to `library()` to load the necessary packages, `map` and `safely` are not base R functions. And your code is not reproducible. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Thanks Rui, sorry about that:

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

Comment: Here is the dput() output. It's a regression, so this is not the easiest to read:

list(Afghanistan = list(result = structure(list(coefficients = c(`(Intercept)` = 118.033713502933, 
gdpcap = -0.0358850778216309), residuals = c(`119` = 5.08209555923342, 
`120` = 2.24286770054146, `121` = 6.25110929678956, `122` = 2.67837932875076....

Comment: Define `g <- function(obj) coef(obj$result)`. Then, `coef_list <- lapply(country_regression, g)` Then `walk(coef_list, hist)`.